# Kotlin data class | add my own variables other than JSON keys

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit and kotlin for my andorid app.

For one of my APIs, I have the following data classes

```
class Set(val set_id: Long, val tickets: List<Ticket>, val timer: Int) {}
class Ticket(val ticket_id: Long, val rows: List<Row>) {}
class Row(val row_id: Long, val row_numbers: List<Int>) {}
```

Sample JSON DATA

```
{
  "set_id": 60942,
  "tickets": [
    {
      "ticket_id": 304706,
      "rows": [
        {
          "row_id": 914116,
          "row_numbers": [
            0,
            11,
            21,
            0,
            42,
            52,
            0,
            76,
            85
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "timer": 12
}
```

`Set` class contains a list of `Ticket` and each ticket has a list of `Row`

My JSON object contains only these values and it is working fine till here. Retrofit mapping is also working.

**Problem:**
I want to add my own a boolean field/variable `isPlaying` for class `Ticket`, which will be updated in the app later. But, this field should be set to true by default.

So I've tried this

```
class Ticket(val ticket_id: Long, val rows: List<Row>, var isPlaying: Boolean = true) {}
```

and this

```
class Ticket(val ticket_id: Long, val rows: List<Row>) {
    var isPlaying: Boolean = true
}
```

NOTE: JSON doesn't have `isPlaying` key, I want it for app logic only.

Both did not work, `isPlaying` is always showing `false`. I want it to be `true` by default.

Please, help me out. Thank you!

Comment: if you need post processing you can set the value to true as suggested https://medium.com/@elye.project/post-processing-on-gson-deserialization-26ce5790137d

Comment: @Raghunandan I'll take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default arguments would not work in data class in the case when objects are instantiated with retrofit due to parsing library used underneath, which probably creates objects without calling constructor. For example `Gson` uses `sun.misc.Unsafe`to create objects.

What you can do - is to add backing property for fields that have default values:

```
class Ticket(
    val ticket_id: Long, 
    val rows: List<Row>, 
    private var _isPlaying: Boolean? = true
) {
    var isPlaying
        get() = _isPlaying ?: true
        set(value) {
            _isPlaying = value
        }
}
```

Comment: Accepted! you were quick.

Comment: Just to clarify - Gson doesn't use reflection, it uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` to reduce reflection overhead. Second thing author mentioned that property should be updated later which isn't possible with read-only property and probably should be changed from `val` to `var`

Comment: @hluhovskyi thanks for clerifying, I have updated my answer

Comment: Is it require _isPlaying to be in the response?

Comment: is it applicable with kotlin `data class` as well? i tried but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is the fact that GSON creates object not via constructor call, but via Unsafe staff. Thus it leads to broken things like null-safety or property initialization.

The only way I know how to workaround your case looks like this:

```
class Ticket(val ticket_id: Long, val rows: List<Row>) {
    private var _isPlaying: Boolean? = null
    var isPlaying: Boolean
        get() = _isPlaying ?: true // <-- default value
        set(value) {
            _isPlaying = value
        }
}
```

Here we create one backing property `_isPlaying` which will be initialized to null by GSON. Next we add custom getter and setter for public property which checks each it is invoked if `_isPlaying` is null. And if so it returns your default value. Otherwise, it returns the value stored in `_isPlaying`

Yes, it looks ugly. Otherwise you should consider using another json library like Jackson which as I know supports Kotlin well.

Comment: thankyou so much. the workaround did the magic. But needs some edits. `var isPlaying: Boolean` is not required

Comment: With your suggested edit you expose nullable field in case when it really doesn't. Of course you can use `field` keyword, but your public interface of model becomes more noisy.

Comment: Yes, but android shows warnings and suggests to change it to field.

Comment: It is just lint warning, it doesn't know your intention and obviously you shouldn't follow such warnings everywhere. As for me, creating clear business models is much more important than one warning from Android lint.

Comment: private var _isPlaying: Boolean? = null ; keeping it null worked for me

Answer (score -1):

With using GsonBuilder setFeildNamePolicy

```
 val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .create()


        val info = gson.fromJson(json, Account::class.java)


data class Account(
        @SerializedName("user_name") var userName: String = "",
        @SerializedName("ticket_id")  var ticketId: String = "",
        @SerializedName("row_id")  var rowId: String = "")

}
```

Comment: I didn't get this, and I don't want to manually map the json string to objects. retrofit does it

Comment: in retrofit you can add .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) in retrofit initializer

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I want to add my own variables to the data class.

Comment: can you add json data in question

Comment: Added sample json data